# Partial refresh of JSF page using ui:repeat and AJAX

Tags: ajax, jsf, jsf-2, uirepeat

I have a page say "Main Page" (Page 1) which looks like a Outlook calendar page having a large number of rows displayed using . Actually, the columns represent "Weeks" and the rows represent "Products". The functionality is that the user can choose a product week combination and create offers for the chosen week.Ideally, as we have a lot of rows (products), we should have ideally implemented pagination but we have not.

We use JSF2 (Mojarra faces that comes with JBoss EAP 6.0). Main Page uses a different bean and Details page uses a different bean and both are in session scope.

When the user creates an offer, instead of refreshing the entire page (i.e. Page1), we just refresh the impacted cells using AJAX. However, the On double clicking the slot(offer), we redirect to a different page (Page2) that displays offer details.

Page 1 - Main Page and Page 2 - Details page.

There are 2 cases from here :

Case 1: User goes from Main page to the details page, just views information on the details page and clicks the close button. In this case, it is enough for me to display Main Page as it was before I opened the details page. To achieve this, we used browser history.back(). However, we faced the below issues :

(a) history.back() works only in Firefox and does not work in Chrome/IE. 
(b) Even if we do history.back(), the page loading is cleary visible and as our page is heavy, it takes a few seconds. I would like to avoid re-rendering of main page again (i.e. make it look like opening a popup from the main page and closing it)

Case 2: User goes from Main Page to Details page and makes certain updates which require us to reflect those updates in the main page.(For example: change color of the slot from red to green on the main page).

Currently, when Details page is closed, we call an API that provides us with refreshed data (so that we do not need to maintain the list of actions that the user had performed) and we reload the entire Main page (Page1). However, as the page takes a long time to load, we are asked to refresh only the affected slots/rows.

So, the problem here is that if we have to achieve the refresh of Main Page through AJAX, we need to maintain a list of activities that has been done on the details page and feed it through AJAX which appears to be a complicated activity. (We also want to avoid calling the API.)

Is there any workaround which helps us to refresh only the selected rows on the Main Page  to minimise the page load time. Can ui:repeat be partially re-rendered ?

PLease advise.

Comment: What is Page 2? Is it a dialog or a page you go using JSF forward rules? Why don't you try to pass the refreshed object when you go back and set it in the table? Anyway you need to analyze where the bottle neck is and what is that API exactly doing. If it's reloading the whole dataset again it will take long to show the view again.

Comment: currently, Page 2 is the Offer details page and is not a dialog. It is a page to which we navigate using JSF forward rules.

Comment: Are Page1 and 2 managed by different beans? Which scope do they use? You're missing lot of relevant info in your question

Comment: hi, I have updated the question with more details as you had asked and tried to explain a bit more clearer than before.